# Python performance of conditional evaluation

Tags: python, performance

I was trying to find out if there's any penalty for negating a boolean when evaluation a conditional statement (python 2.6.6). I first tried this simple test (no `else` branch)

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("if not True: pass", number=100000)
0.011913061141967773
>>> timeit.timeit("if True: pass", number=100000)
0.018882036209106445
```

So I though the results where skewed because the pass statement might be translated to a noop which is at least *some* operation.

I did a second try and got these results:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("a=False\nif not a: pass\nelse: pass", number=100000)
0.02387714385986328
>>> timeit.timeit("a=False\nif a: pass\nelse: pass", number=100000)
0.015386819839477539
>>> timeit.timeit("a=True\nif a: pass\nelse: pass", number=100000)
0.02389812469482422
>>> timeit.timeit("a=True\nif not a: pass\nelse: pass", number=100000)
0.015424966812133789
```

I didn't expect to see any large penalty but from this results it looks like evaluating the `else` branch is cheaper than the implicit `then` branch. And the difference is huge!

So The third attempt return these results:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("if True: a=1\nelse: a=1", number=100000)
0.022008895874023438
>>> timeit.timeit("if not True: a=1\nelse: a=1", number=100000)
0.022121906280517578
```

And finally I got the expected results. Though out of curiosity I tried a last time:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("if False: a=1\nelse: a=1", number=100000)
0.02385997772216797
>>> timeit.timeit("if not False: a=1\nelse: a=1", number=100000)
0.02244400978088379
```

And that's it...
I have no idea why the negated condition leading to the `then` branch is faster.

What might be happening?

All those results are reproducible on my computer, it doesn't matter how many times I run them I get pretty much the same results.

I think the first tests where skewed because the compiler might have removed the `else: pass` part altogether. Is that possible?

Might all this results be related to the branch predictor in the CPU?

Any other possible culprits?

Comment: I can't reproduce those results at all (on Win7 x64, Python 3.3.0 or Python 2.7.3). In all cases, the differences are nearly negligible and not skewed in any consistent direction.

Comment: The times are not faster or slower, but they are within margin of error when measuring time of execution. Repeat these tests more than once and for a bigger number of iterations. Why are you concerned with a performance of boolean expressions? In iterpreted languages such as Python differences should be negligible, because none of these checks is translated directly into assembler, but the constant cost of a conditional expression will dominate the result.

Comment: @Tim: thanks for the feedback then this is related to the cpu architecture

Comment: @Rafal: But I never got results that supported that the opposite case was faster. That's what I found strange, I would have expected random results...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, the "real world" news: if you really are in a situation where writing "if not" or "if ..pass else..." would impact the performance of your application, I'd suggest you did some serious profiling, and rewrite your inner loop in native code -either using Cython or C (and even other options, such as Fortran - Python is good at integrating).

Otherwise, I'd say these are irrelevant implementation details. Disassembling your code sequences with "dis" could show what is going on - but optimization at this level is of no pratical value in Python whatsoever - a single function call, even one implicit by using operators, would require about an extra order of magnitude of time than compared with the exection of the `if` statement.

Here:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile("if not True: pass", "None", "exec",))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (True)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE         9
              6 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 9)
        >>    9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(compile("if True: pass", "None", "exec",))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (True)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        9
              6 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 9)
        >>    9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE        
>>>
```

As you can see, there is no difference in the bytecode generated for
using "not" or not - but for the op of the jumping operator, which should take the same time in both cases.

Comment: don't forget about Fortran!  You could re-write the inner loop in that if you wanted :).  I looked at `dis` for the first tests.  One translates to `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE`, the other to `POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE`.  It doesn't seem like that should make any difference here though.

Comment: Though I'm proficient in C, I've never learned the python C API -- `f2py` is just too easy to use for me to switch from writing simple fortran extensions (although, supposedly, you can use it to wrap C code too if you're motivated ...)

Comment: @jsbueno: Thanks for the `dis` advice! I didn't know it! In my python version (2.6.6) I have a `jump if - pop - jump - pop` instead of the `pop_jump_if - Jump`. And this is just out of curiosity more than performance improvement.

Comment: @mgilson: Indeed I have seen fortran array handling blazing when compared to C (even when compared to numpy, but that's just because of the memory allocation when passing python data to fortran... I guess)

Comment: Though it's not completely answering why this happens, it points to the fact the the generated the code it's just the same, and that's the point. There are JZ and JNZ Instructions, so this shouldn't make any difference. Not sure why then this is reproducible, but I guess it's CPU arch + cache + cosmic rays.